# Send double-click with Autohotkey

Tags: autohotkey, remapping, double-click

I'd like to remap the middle mouse button to double-click using autohotkey.

A simple remapping (4th mutton -> middle button) worked fine using `XButton1::MButton` but I couldn't find a way to remap a button to send a left-button doubleclick.

I've already tried `MButton::LButton 2` and `MButton::LButton & LButton` but those didn't work (apparently this syntax is only used in different AHK statements but not in remappings).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nevermind, found the answer:

```
MButton::Click 2
```

Comment: If it's the answer, you can mark it as such with the green checkmark.

Comment: Oops! Didn't know that.

Answer (score 2):

This will specify which button you want to press:

```
+LButton::
send {LButton 2}
Return
```

LButton is left click
MButton is middle click
RButton is right click

Comment: I already had a valid answer ;) Thanks anyway