# Ctrl + Mouse click to paste text using Autohotkey

Tags: autohotkey

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Send double-click with Autohotkey](https://superuser.com/questions/273830/send-double-click-with-autohotkey)

I'm trying paste text using Ctrl and right click in SQL Management Studio. I have this which works great in notepad++ but not in SSMS. I have the mouseclick there because I want it to paste where the mouse is. (I don't want the extra step of manually left clicking the location before pasting).

```
^RButton::
    MouseClick, left, , , 1
    Send ^v
```

By default, Ctrl+Left Click in SSMS selects the word (like double clicking a word) so what ends up happening when I use the hotkey is SSMS selects the word and then pastes the text overwriting what was there.

Is there a way I can have SSMS ignore the fact that I'm holding the ctrl key? I tried doing shift+right click, but it gives me a similar issue... it selects a text range before pasting.

Windows XP, latest version of AHK

edit: Grumble grumble, 2 min later I found the answer from here
[Send double-click with Autohotkey](https://superuser.com/questions/273830/send-double-click-with-autohotkey)

```
send {LButton 2}   ; use this line instead of mouseclick
```

Please delete or close

Comment: Why not add your edit as a reply, and mark it as correct? It seems a useful answer to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found my answer.

```
send {LButton 2}   ; use this line instead of mouseclick
```